# cython wrapping of a templated c++ class gives undefined symbol

Tags: c++, templates, cython

This seems like it should be a very simple question, and I've seen similar discussions here, but nothing that quite tackles this problem. I have a class written in c++ that I would like to access with cython. The simple example below illustrates the problem, it compiles just fine, however, I get an ImportError when I use it.

```
//element.h

template <typename T>
class element{
    public:
        element(T);
        ~element();
        T data;
};
```

and

```
//element.cc

#include  "element.h"

template <typename T>
element<T>::element(T _data){
    data = _data;
}

template <typename T>
    element<T>::~element(){
}
```

it's accessed through the following simple cython

```
cdef extern from "element.h":
    cdef cppclass element[T]:
        element(T) except +
        T data

cdef element[int] *el = new element[int](3)
print el.data
```

and compiled in place with

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("example",
               ['example.pyx','./element.cc'],
               language = "c++")]

setup(cmdclass = {'build_ext':build_ext},
    name = 'example',
    ext_modules = ext_modules)
```

However, when I try to import the resulting shared library, I get

```
ImportError: .../example.so: undefined symbol: _ZN7elementIiEC1Ei
```

If I simply strip out all the templating and force ints for example, the code compiles just fine (as before) but this time it runs. So, in other words, this works fine.

```
//element.h                                                                                                                                                                                             
class element{
    public:
        element(int);
        ~element();
        int data;
};
```

and

```
//element.cc
#include  "element.h"

element::element(int _data){
    data = _data;
}

element::~element(){
}
```

and

```
//example.pyx
cdef extern from "element.h":

    cdef cppclass element:

        element(int) except +
        int data

cdef element *el = new element(3)
print el.data
```

What am I doing wrong with the templating in the first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement template in one header file instead of split into `element.cc`. When I run `c++file` command it shows that compiler failed to link *element constructor* definition

```
$ c++filt _ZN7elementIiEC1Ei
element<int>::element(int)
```

Comment: Ah, of course - really nothing to do with cython and everything to do with templating properly. Thanks so much!